# Implementing DFS for networkX graph traversal

Tags: python, networkx

I have implemented DFS to print out the path from one tube station to another in a `networkX` graph for [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gHCHs1719sZOC2eZ5mShPtUMbnwfFDCFaM9gWxLRaOQ/edit?usp=sharing) data:

[image]

```py
def dfs(nxobject, initial, goal, compute_exploration_cost=False, reverse=False):

    frontier = [{'label':initial, 'parent':None}]  
    explored = {initial}
    number_of_explored_nodes = 1 

    while frontier:
        node = frontier.pop() 
        number_of_explored_nodes += 1
        if node['label']==goal:
            if compute_exploration_cost:
                print('number of explorations = {}'.format(number_of_explored_nodes))
            return node

        neighbours = reversed(list(nxobject.neighbors(node['label']))) if reverse else nxobject.neighbors(node['label'])
        for child_label in neighbours:

            child = {'label':child_label, 'parent':node}
            if child_label not in explored:
                frontier.append(child) # added to the right of the list, so it is a LIFO
                explored.add(child_label)      
    return None
```

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('tubedata.csv',header=None)

edgelist = data.apply(lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[3]),axis=1).to_list()

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edgelist)
```

However, when I call the `dfs` method, I keep getting `None`:

```py
solution = dfs(G, 'Euston', '"Victoria"')
```

The output should be as:

```
['Euston', 'WarrenStreet', 'OxfordCircus', 'GreenPark', 'Victoria']
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Victoria with or without quotes? Is this a typo?

Comment: You have a typo... If you remove double quotes, your code works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes on `'"Victoria"'`:

```
>>> dfs(G, 'Euston', 'Victoria')
{'label': 'Victoria',
 'parent': {'label': 'Green Park',
  'parent': {'label': 'Piccadilly Circus',
   'parent': {'label': 'Leicester Square',
    'parent': {'label': 'Covent Garden',
     'parent': {'label': 'Holborn',
      'parent': {'label': 'Russell Square',
       'parent': {'label': "King's Cross St. Pancras",
        'parent': {'label': 'Euston', 'parent': None}}}}}}}}}
```

But you can use [`nx.shortest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html):

```
>>> nx.shortest_path(G, 'Euston', 'Victoria')
['Euston', 'Warren Street', 'Oxford Circus', 'Green Park', 'Victoria']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am still getting none as show here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p2iGLwolAiHncGDJv7soDU5s4yo0g_9M/view?usp=sharing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Awesome. I can't explain this behavior. I used your code (copy/paste) and this gave the output above. For information, I use Networkx 2.6.3, Pandas 1.3.4 and Python 3.9.7.